# Replacing part of a string in a list in python

Tags: python

For example i have list of a name written diffently

```
list1 = ["jai.kumar","jaikumar","j_kumar","jk","kumar-jai","ja.ku"]
for str in l1:
 if str == “jai”
  str.replace (“jai”,”firstname”)
   if str == “ja”
    str.replace (“ja”,”first 2 character of firstname”)
     if str == “j”
      str.replace (“j”,”first character of firstname”)
 if str == “kumar”
  str.replace (“kumar”,”lastname”)
   if str == “ku”
    str.replace (“ku”,”first 2 character of lasttname”)
     if str == “k”
      str.replace (“k”,”first character of lastname”)
print(list1)
```

How do i correct the above code or is there an easier way to do it?

My expected output is

```
 list1 = ["firstname.lastname","firstnamelastname","first character of firstname_lastname",.....]
```

Comment: This does not help the OP.
@OP Maybe Regular Expressions would be easier with what you want to do here. Could you explain what you try to achieve exactly in order that we can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant sth like this?:

```
if str == “jai”:
    str.replace (“jai”,”firstname”)
    if str == “ja”:
        str.replace (“ja”,”first 2 character of firstname”)
        if str == “j”:
            str.replace (“j”,”first character of firstname”)
```

If yes(remeber of semicolon at the end of 'if') then this code won't work as you wish because second and third if is nestled inside previous IFs.
So if first condition -> str=="jai" fails then you don't check the next ones.
It should be:

```
if str == “jai”:
    str.replace (“jai”,”firstname”)
elif str == “ja”:
    str.replace (“ja”,”first 2 character of firstname”)
elif str == “j”:
    str.replace (“j”,”first character of firstname”)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it for different set of first names and last names ? 
for example

Comment: l1 = ["jai","sharath","ravi","aditya"]

         l2 = ["singh","kumar","sharma","rao"]

         l3 = ["jai.singh@gmail.com","s_kumar@gmail.com","ravis@gmail.com","ad-r@gmail.com"]

Comment: and get an output like 

l3 =["firstname.lastname@gmail.com","firstcharacter_lastname@gmail.com",....etc]

Comment: You mean you want to merge multiple sets? In python world it is as simple as using '+' operator ;) for instance in your example: l1 + l3 will result in new list containing elements from both. 
PS: if you like my answers don't forget to vote them up or check as solution.

Comment: No I dont want to merge lists, the 3 lists are already given. I need to compare the 3rd list with 1st and 2nd list and find a common pattern.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you're defining a list "list1" then operating on a list "l1" which is not defined, I'll assume this is a typo. Also you're indentation is fucked up and you're missing tons of colons after your ifs, I'll correct all that, if I shouldn't have and missed the purpose, please tell me.

second, you're using == for comparing strings which will only be true for exact matches. What you're looking for is the "in" operator.

thirdly, you're using string.replace("str1","str2") incorrectly, string.replace() returns a shallow copy of string where "str1" instances have been replaced by "str2", so what you'd want to do would be more like str = str.replace("1","2").

Fourth,

```
for str in list1:
```

creates an str variable that is an alias of the list1 element, and reassigning str breaks the alias, meaning str = something will not modify list1.

and lastly, you won't encounter "ja" if you already encountered "jai" I assume, for that reason using elifs is more efficient, rather than testing for "ja" and "j" after already having found "jai"

All in all, your code would need to be something like this:

```
list1 = ["jai.kumar","jaikumar","j_kumar","jk","kumar-jai","ja.ku"]
for i in range(len(list1)):
 if “jai” in list1[i]:
  list1[i] = list1[i].replace (“jai”,”firstname”)
 elif “ja” in list1[i]:
  list1[i] = list1[i].replace (“ja”,”first 2 character of firstname”)
 elif “j” in list1[i]:
  list1[i] = list1[i].replace (“j”,”first character of firstname”)
 if “kumar” in list1[i]:
  list1[i] = list1[i].replace (“kumar”,”lastname”)
 elif “ku” in list1[i]:
  str = str.replace (“ku”,”first 2 character of lasttname”)
 elif "k” in list1[i]:
  list1[i] = list1[i].replace (“k”,”first character of lastname”)
print(list1)
```

Hope this answer your questions, let me know if anything is not clear.